# Reload dataTable after form submit inside colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, colorbox

I have a page **test.php** where I fetch data using jQuery DataTables. There is an "Add Note" button in the same page which opens an ajax form inside colorbox. The form submission is working fine but I want to refresh DataTables when a record is inserted in my database.

**DataTable:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

**Ajax Form:** Note that this form load inside colorbox popup

```
if (error == false) {
    $.post("submit.php", $("#add_note").serialize(), function (result) {
        if (result == 'success') {
            $('#error_msg').remove();
            $('#success_msg').fadeIn(500);
            // want to reload DataTables here
        } else {
            $('#error_msg').fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
}
```

**My Solution:** I try different methods and the below method refresh the page content but only for the first time. If I want to submit form for the 2nd time without page refresh, then the ajax form stopped working.

```
$(".content-wrapper").load('test.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading DataTables through its [ajax option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) (which I'd recommend for this particular case), you can reload its data using the [API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload%28%29).

First, keep the DataTables instance in a global variable, and then call the API using such variable:

```
var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
   table = $('#example').DataTable();
});

if (error == false) {
    $.post("submit.php", $("#add_note").serialize(), function (result) {
        if (result == 'success') {
            $('#error_msg').remove();
            $('#success_msg').fadeIn(500);
            table.ajax.reload();
        } else {
            $('#error_msg').fadeIn(500);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well I am basic initialisation but will check with ajax option also. Is there any way to just reload the `div`, I try the above method but it doesn't worked.

Comment: If you use the ajax method within datatables, you won't need to reload the div, Datatables will handle the data reloading automatically (cool, huh?)